# invalid empty ssh agent socket, make sure SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set How to set SSH_AUTH_SOCK for docker build?

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, dockerfile, ssh-keys

I'm trying to deploy a  docker-compose app in PyCharm, Windowsb10. Running the command:

```
set "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1" && docker build --ssh default=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} -f docker/Dockerfile -t basketball_backend_api_core .
```

Results in:

```
could not parse ssh: [default=]: invalid empty ssh agent socket, make sure SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set
```

Where should I set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK?

UPD: Status of my OpenSSH Authentication Agent is running

Answer (score 6):

It seems that either the `--ssh` argument doesn't accept empty values as an argument.

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
set "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1" && docker build --ssh default=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} -f docker/Dockerfile -t basketball_backend_api_core .
```

or you [may need to run ssh-add to add private key identities to the authentication agent first for this to work](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds).

```
before_script:
  ##
  ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
  ## (change apt-get to yum if you use an RPM-based image)
  ##
  - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

  ##
  ## Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
  ##
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

  ##
  ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
  ## without extra base64 encoding.
  ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
  ##
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
```

from [Gitlab's docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor).

Comment: The first approach only works if you use bind mounts to pass the socket through to the child process. Since your answer doesn't show how to do this, only the second approach has any chance of being successful.

Comment: Thank you! If i run  eval $(ssh-agent)
 command in bash i have results that -bash: ssh-agent: command not found
and after that docker as well not found, but if i run this via terminal it results in eval : The term 'eval' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, etc. Where should i run the commands?

Comment: Have you tried installing `openssh-client`?